# .serialize to apply only to one form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a page where I show two times the same form. The page is a wizard and the form is displayed two times but each time with a different action on success.
The point is that when I submit the form I use serialize to collect the data and serialize will collect the values from both the forms. I need to deduplicate the result of serialize otherwise on the backend I will receive two times the value. How can I do it?

```js
$('.login-button').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var submit_val= $('.login_form').serialize();
                  var step = $(this).parent().find('.step').val();
            dest = "https://"+domain+"/login/login.php";
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: dest,
                data: submit_val,
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data){
                //actions on success...
                }
              });
            
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--first step of the wizard - first instance of the form-->
<form role="form" class="login_form subscription-form form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="username_login" placeholder="Username" class="input-box form-control">
        <input type="password" name="password_login" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
        <input type="hidden" class="step" value="1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn standard-button login-button">Accedi</button>
</form>
<!--different step of the wizard - again the same form-->
<form role="form" class="login_form subscription-form form-inline">
    <input type="text" name="username_login" placeholder="Username" class="input-box form-control">
        <input type="password" name="password_login" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
        <input type="hidden" class="step" value="4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn standard-button login-button">Accedi</button>
</form>
```

The result of serialize will be:

```
username_login=user_name&password_login=user_password&username_login=&password_login=
```

where user_name and user_password are the values inserted by the user in one of the two forms

Comment: They both are very identical. What is the reason behind having them 2 times? Are they for different reasons? AFAIK, this the default behavior. May be instead of serialize, just send values that you need on server. Or just give the form a unique id per wizard and send it respectively.

Comment: @Pirate _The page is a wizard and the form is displayed two times but each time with a different action on success_ as I said in the question. Assigning an ID i'd have to duplicate the javascript code that sends the form. I also know I can build the query manually but I'd prefer to keep it with serialize so that if I manipulate the form the javascript will be always valid. Otherwise I will have to manually adapt the query each time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should also use `.parent()` when serializing:

```
var submit_val= $(this).parent().serialize();
```

**Demo:**

```js
$('.login-button').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var submit_val = $(this).parent().serialize();
  console.log("Serialized: " + submit_val)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!--first step of the wizard - first instance of the form-->
<form role="form" class="login_form subscription-form form-inline">
  <input type="text" name="username_login" placeholder="Username" class="input-box form-control">
  <input type="password" name="password_login" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
  <input type="hidden" class="step" value="1">
  <button type="submit" class="btn standard-button login-button">Accedi</button>
</form>

<!--different step of the wizard - again the same form-->
<form role="form" class="login_form subscription-form form-inline">
  <input type="text" name="username_login" placeholder="Username" class="input-box form-control">
  <input type="password" name="password_login" placeholder="Password" class="input-box form-control">
  <input type="hidden" class="step" value="4">
  <button type="submit" class="btn standard-button login-button">Accedi</button>
</form>
```

Comment: wow! that's something I didn't think about! Thank you very much, it will do the job.